# An exchange student is staying up all night and playing video games

Tags: router, vpn

I have an exchange student living in my home, and it's kind of a friend's son kinda thing, so I can't kick him out. He stays up all night playing video games, he might be using a vpn so I can't find his ip address on the router (calix) and I need to put a time limit on his computer (permission from his parents given). HELP! (I'm not a genius on tech either)

Comment: turnoff the router when you go to sleep?

Comment: start by telling the guest that he's causing you some specific problems (draining data limit, etc.) and would he please stop; if that doesn't work, ask your friend to pass the message on; if _that_ doesn't work, try technical means.

Comment: his computer will still have an IP address and MAC which can be blocked if the router supports it - the problem is a lot of routers dont support these blocks, and depending on how smart he is, it could turn into an arms race (You can fake a MAC address)

Comment: So your the proxy dad now? either he follows your rules or he can live with his real dad.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I can't seem to find his ip address, I look through the devices list and don't see his computer, I can assign a device to everyone, (I'm sure he's using the internet) and when he's watching videos (youtube) I don't see a single thing pop up in the 'web activity log'. I'm not trying to control his life, but he's sleeping in school and his father is a real good friend of mine.

Comment: Start -> cmd enter -> "ipconfig /all" will give you the Mac addresses of wired and wireless adapters in windows. arp -a from the command prompt will show you all the active Mac/IP pairs. Let us know the model number of the calix please. It's impossible to know what features it supports without it! I personally did not believe in internet addiction until I witnessed it with a room mate. It can be a life changing problem for some people.

Comment: Did you tell him his parents have placed limits on him?  Give at least a 30min warning first.  If so, go down to basement at 8pm or whatever and turn the circuit break off.  No proxy can defeat no electricity.  Some games are single player, and don't require internet access.  You may be looking in vain.

Comment: White list your IP, all other slow down or get cut off at whatever time you choose.  Or simply unplug all the cables except the one from your PC to the router.